# Trace of $2021×2021$ symmetric matrix where each row is a permutation of $\{1,2,\cdots,2021\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, trace, symmetric-matrices

> Suppose that $M$ is a $2021\times 2021$ symmetric matrix such that the entries of each row is set by rearranging $\{1,2,\cdots,2021\}$. Then what is the trace of $M$?

We know that ${\rm tr}(M)$ is the sum of all eigenvalues of $M$. I can see that $\frac{2021\cdot 2022}{2}$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ since $$M(1,1,\cdots,1)^{\rm T}=(1+\cdots+2021)\cdot(1,1,\cdots,1)^{\rm T} .$$ But after that I’m stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The trace is also the sum of all diagonal entries of $M$. So $$\operatorname{tr}(M)=\sum_{i=1}^{2021} m_{ii},$$ where each of the $m_{ii}$'s are the diagonal entries of $M$ which in turn is one element from $\{1,2,\dots,2021 \}$. Then $\max(\operatorname{tr}(M))=2021\times2021$ and $\min(\operatorname{tr}(M))=2021$. "I" don't see how any more information about the trace can be obtained from the given info.

Comment: tricky. There seems to be an answer for odd prime size

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fix $a\in\{1,...,2021\}$.

By hypothesis, $a$ occurs exactly once in each row, so the total number of occurrences of $a$ is $2021$.

Since the matrix is symmetric, the number of off-diagonal occurrences of $a$ must be even, hence $a$ must occur an odd number of times on the diagonal, and in particular, at least once.

By the pigeonhole principle, each $a\in\{1,...,2021\}$ must occur exactly once on the diagonal, hence the trace is
$$
1+\cdots+2021
=
\frac{2021{\,\cdot\,}2022}{2}
$$

Comment: Ignore my previous comments, I just realized the significance of the symmetry requirement.

Comment: @quasi could you please confirm if I am interpreting your PHP step right?  There are  2021 elements (pigeons) which have to occur an odd no.  of times each in the 2021 places (pigeonholes) of the diagonals  so each must occur exactly once.

Comment: @insipidintegrator:  Yes. The key is that an odd number of times implies at least once.

Comment: Thanks @quasi !.